# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, token

I have been trying to fix this problem, but nothing comes to mind anymore...
Web application to use Tokens, but something keeps me back.

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
```

Here is the whole code:

```
 namespace DutchTreat.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private readonly SignInManager<StoreUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<StoreUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public AccountController(ILogger<AccountController> logger, SignInManager<StoreUser> signInManager, UserManager<StoreUser> userManager, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _config = config;
        }
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
            }
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (Request.Query.Keys.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].First());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Shop", "App");
                    }
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to login");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        //Create the token
                        var claims = new[]
                        {
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, new Guid().ToString()),
                        };

                        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
                    }
                }

            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear - `IController` does not support indexing, so you can't do `_config["Tokens:Key"]`.

Comment: I know what it means, but i'm following video courses and if they can do it, how can't i?

Comment: Can you go to the definition 'IConfiguration', press F12 while having cursor on it. Share that info? Also Share how you are setting up the Dependency container possibly in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is .NET Core there is a `GetValue<T>()` function, or a `GetValue()` function if you want to default to a string.

I use this as i get the same error.

refer here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.getvalue?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_GetValue__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_String_)

however th basic usage of it in your case is:

`_config.GetValue<string>("Token:Key")`

or

`_config.GetValue("Token:Key")`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! Solved it!

Comment: please remember to mark this as a correct answer, and your welcome, glad i could help

Answer (score 39):

The `_config.Item["Tokens:Key"]` is pretty much legal task, the error seems the `Iconfiguration` referenced to `AutoMapper.Configuration` instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`

Comment: I'm doing the same course and this is exactly the answer to the problem.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  When injecting Iconfiguration visual studio for some reason defaults to automapper. Not something you'd expect.

Comment: I agree with @Mike, this is a subtle VS configuration difference and is important to mark as a correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

I'm following the same Check your using statements and make sure that your IConfiguration is coming from

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

and not from

Automapper.Configuration

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting this because you can end up here with the same exact error message if you are accidentally using the wrong namespace for IConfiguration in dotnet core.

Use:
`using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`

Instead of:
`using Castle.Core.Configuration;`

Answer (score 1):

The exception is telling you that you can't using indexing (`[]`) with `IConfiguration`

Are you looking for `_config.Item["Tokens:Key"]` instead?

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: It returns IConfiguration does not contain a definition for Item, and no accessible extension method Item accepting a first argument of type IConfiguration...
The videos that i am watching use the syntax that i wrote and it works for them... I just don't understand it.